# Minimizing moment of discrete event

Tags: probability, optimization, expectation, maxima-minima

If we have $V_i$ a random variable such that $E[V_i] = 0$ and $E[V_i^2] = 1$
What distribution of $V_i$ would minimise $E[V_i^4]$?

My intuition is that it would be $V_i = \pm 1$ with probability $1/2$. I am however stuck on how to rigorously demonstrate this.

$min_{(V_i , p(V_i))}\sum_{i = 1}^n V_i^4 p(V_i)$ such that : $\sum_{i = 1}^n V_i^2 p(V_i)$.

My above intuition indeed matches the constraint. Any hints would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.  This is answered in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis in the section on Moors' interpretation.  Adapting to this question:

Let $Z=V_i^2$, so you seek to minimize $E[V_i^4]=E[Z^2] = Var(Z) + E[Z]^2$.  But by construction $E[Z]=E[V_i^2]=1$ so you are just minimizing $Var(Z)$.  By choosing $V_i= \pm1$, $Z=1$ always and so $Var(Z)=0$, the minimum possible value.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy that comes to mind:

Remove a middle value, and assign its probability mass to the most extreme values in such a way that the mean remains zero. Now scale the values such that the second moment is 1 again. If you can show that this always results in a fourth moment that is smaller, then your desired conclusion should follow.